Multiple Data Source with AWS Q Business
Does AWS Q Business actually able to answer questions from data sources other than docx or web crawler. I have been testing with Confluence and Slack. Both data sync success, items are indexed. But Q refuse to answer any questions and respond Sorry, I could not find relevant information to complete your request. If it refuses to answer questions from data connector source, I don't know what is the point of using Q Business. Plus, there is no information about what Q is actually crawling or what is actually indexed. CloudWatch don't show any of them. This is really disappointing.
Images are here: image 1, image 2 (I am sorry but stackoverflow not allow me to post image)
Anyone have the same situation?
There is another stackoverflow that seem have the same problem: link
